# Translating sentence of Luxun

Tags: translation, literary-chinese

Lu Xun says [here](https://zh.m.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E6%91%A9%E7%BE%85%E8%A9%A9%E5%8A%9B%E8%AA%AA):

> 夫國民發展，功雖有在於懷古，然其懷也，思理朗然，如鑒明鏡，時時上征，時時反顧…

夫 is probably the literary auxiliary for introducing a new topic.

有，I assume means “partly”

思理：I’m very unsure about this. Might go with 思辨能力: the ability for analytical thought
朗然:brightly, clearly?

My translation attempt:

> As for the development of the populace, the merit in part depends on keeping the Ancient Tradition. But it’s keeping must happen with clear analytical thought, as a mirror or a clear lens, at times proceeding, at times looking back...

There are many parts about which I am uncertain. Can you point out mistakes or improvements?

Comment: 大端合辙，虽然，仍有未尽美之处。“有”表存在，古今因之。“思理朗然”应为“（其怀古之）思（之）理，朗然”，译作今文，私以为作“（然其怀也），思路和道理都清楚明白”。是陈述也。“鉴”为动词，窥镜而照是为鉴，而鉴镜之喻，上推汉唐。《资治通鉴》不为“鉴于往事，有资于治道”乎？据此“如鉴明镜”，当译为“就如以古为镜，反观自照”。“上征而反顾”无谬，故不细说。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your translation is mostly accurate. But I don't think 有 means "partly" directly. In Chinese, 有 usually means "there is/are". So a more "verbatim" translation would be

..., although there are merits in keeping the ancient tradition,...

with the following correspondence

虽=although

有=there are

功=merits

在于=in

怀古=keeping…

As for 思理, you may know that 思 means "think, thought", and 理 means "reason". So 思理朗然 means

with clear thinking and reasoning

or

the thinking and reasoning must be clear